# Calling a method based on user input (text-based game)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to make a text-based game, and I'd like to add a feature where, based on the user's input in the command line (or Python shell), it detects a corresponding method, and returns it.

For example, when the user types in `'legal moves!'` in the command line:

```
>>> legal moves!
'You have 10 legal moves, which are...'
```

Or something like that.

I know that if I make a class, and a method called `legal_moves(self)`, the user would be able to type in `CLASSNAME.legal_moves()` to call the same thing, but I'm trying to make it as simple as possible for the player, assuming they know nothing about python.

Currently I have something like this, but I'm not quite sure exactly how to make it work:

```
def MyClass():

    def __init__(self):
        player_words = input
        if player_words == "help me":
            return self.help_menu()

    def help_menu(self):
        print("To receive help...")
```

Comment: This is quite broad - what exactly are you stuck on? Your current code doesn't even seem to **call** `input`, and it's not clear why you do that in `__init__`. How wide a range of inputs is acceptable from the user? Could you create a method to tell them the valid inputs?

Answer (score 1):

You are very close!

First, you have to use `class` and not `def` to declare a class:

```
class MyClass():
```

And then, use `input()` in order to get user input.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options; you could use the [`getattr()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to turn strings into attributes on your instance; this includes access to methods:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        player_words = input()
        player_words = player_words.lower().replace(' ', '_')
        try:
            getattr(self, player_words)()
        except AttributeError:
            print("Sorry, there is no such command")

    def help_me(self):
        print("To receive help...")
```

This translates `'Help me'` into `help_me` and finds the corresponding method to call.

To list all the possible methods, you could use the [`inspect.getmembers()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers), together with the [`inspect.ismethod()` predicate function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismethod) to list all methods your class offers; you'll have to filter these as you don't want to present the `__init__` method to your visitor. Perhaps you could overload the `__doc__` attribute for functions for this purpose; it contains the [function documentation string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-docstrings):

```
from inspect import getmembers, ismethod

def is_documented_method(ob):
    return ismethod(ob) and ob.__doc__

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        available_methods = getmembers(self, is_documented_method)
        help_info = [
            (name.replace('_', ' ').title(), func.__doc__)
            for name, func in available_methods]
        for name, documentation in help_info:
            print(name, documentation, sep=': ')
        player_words = input()
        player_words = player_words.lower().replace(' ', '_')
        try:
            getattr(self, player_words)()
        except AttributeError:
            print("Sorry, there is no such command")

    def help_me(self):
        """Provide help on all commands"""
        print("To receive help...")

    def frob_the_foobar(self):
        """Frobbing the Foobar will ..."""
        print("Frobbing the Foobar, sir!")
```

Demo of the latter:

```
>>> MyClass()
Frob The Foobar: Frobbing the Foobar will ...
Help Me: Provide help on all commands
help me
To receive help...
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x1114829e8>
>>> MyClass()
Frob The Foobar: Frobbing the Foobar will ...
Help Me: Provide help on all commands
Frob The Foobar
Frobbing the Foobar, sir!
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x111482b38>
```